# jQuery Validate addMethod with multiple conditionals

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am having a hard time getting validation to work with multiple conditionals.

I have tried several different ways but none seem to work.

This works:

```
return this.optional(element) || value != "somevalue";
```

But if I add another conditional, neither of them work:

```
return this.optional(element) || value != "somevalue" || value != "someothervalue";
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There are no syntax errors here and we're not mind-readers. So without knowing what you're trying to do, how can we troubleshoot the flaws in your logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use parenthesis for readability and so that the `this.optional(element)` is always compared to everything else as a group.

```
return this.optional(element) || ( value != "somevalue" || value != "someothervalue");
```

If `value = somevalue`...

`value != "somevalue"` => `FALSE`

`value != "someothervalue"` => `TRUE`

So `(FALSE || TRUE)` => `TRUE`.

By using another `OR`, it will always pass validation and I don't *think* this is what you wanted.

---

So I really think you meant to do this...

```
return this.optional(element) || ( value != "somevalue" && value != "someothervalue");
```

However, without knowing your logic, it's really impossible to say for sure what's going wrong.